# Can't get "__parsed_extra" data

Tags: arrays, reactjs, papaparse

I'm trying to get the data stored in a property called `__parsed_extra` (see image):

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";

export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };

    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    var csvFilePath = require("./training13Sep.csv");
    Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      download: true,
      complete: this.updateData
    });
  }

  updateData(result) {
    const data = result.data;
    this.setState({ data: data });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data[15].__parsed_extra[1]);

    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Player</th>
          <th>Nationality</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Player Number</th>
          <th>Signed</th>
          <th>Wage</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Height</th>
          <th>Weight</th>
          <th>Social Networks</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error messsage:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '__parsed_extra' of undefined

What's going wrong?

Comment: The error shows you the issue, does reading the error message give you enough information to understand your issue?

Comment: no i don't know why it cannot read the propety can you help me with the syntax?